# c# regex split ignoring characters like "=" "-"

Tags: c#, regex, split

My code is

```
string sentence = ".a -w =e ?a";
string[] words = Regex.Split(sentence, @"(?![-\/.:~+=!>?])\W+");
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

outputs `.a w e a` but I want it to output `.a -w =e ?a`

I'm a little clueless on coding so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: If you're new to coding, it's a lot easier to use `String.Split` to split on the empty spaces between what you're trying to capture.  `sentence.Split(' ');`.

Comment: The string you want to output matches the string that you input; please can you clarify what you're hoping to do?  i.e. currently `string sentence = ".a -w =e ?a"; Console.WriteLine(sentence);`  would meet your stated requirement...

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Based on your expected output, it looks like you want to split with spaces only. I'm not sure why you have all that stuff in the regex. What exactly are you expecting to see with `words[0]`, `words[1]`, etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code as below would return the desired result.  The `Split()` method will split the string based on the input and return an array.  The regex split would be better for more complex split requirements.

```
string sentence = ".a -w =e ?a";
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
   Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the output: a, w, e, a:

```
string sentence = ".a -w =e ?a";
string[] words = Regex.Split(sentence, @"[\W_]+"); 
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

This splits on anything that's not a letter or a number.

**Explanation**

- `\W` = not a letter, number, or underscore (see http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
- `_` = since we only want letter or numbers in our words, also include the underscore as a character to split on
- `[`...`]` - this says to split on either `\W` or `_`; as opposed to `\W` immediately followed by `_`.
- `+` - this says if there are multiple split characters sequentially to treat them as 1; i.e. `a - b` results in `a`,`b` rather than `a`,,,`b`.

Comment: `[...]` is set notation that doesn't say split. It is a set, which will split on....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Split` but can simply match anything that is not a space.

```
Regex.Matches(".a -w =e ?a", @"[^\s]+")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => mt.Value)
```

Will return an array of words

[image]

---

`[^\s]+` says match anything from this set `[...]` which is *not* `^` a space `\s`. `+` one or more of those characters (characters which are not a space).

---

Note that I wrote a blog article, almost ten years ago now, about the pitfall of using regex split on multiple lines and running into problems.

[Regex Split Pitfalls Over Multiple Lines](http://omegacoder.com/?p=211)